# Identity between multivariable rational functions with different variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $m\leq n$ and let $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $g(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ be two non-constant rational functions over $\mathbb R$ such such that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=g(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ for all $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.
In addition, we assume that $f$ depends on each of its variables and the same for $g$ (so $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1$, for example, is not an option). I want to prove that if , then $m=n$.

Here is my attempt: Suppose that $m<n$. Hence
$0\equiv\frac{\partial(f-g)}{\partial x_n}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}$. Therefore, $f$ is of the form
$$
  f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})+f_2(x_n)
  $$
where $f_2\not\equiv \text{const}$ since $f$ depends on $x_n$. Hence
$$
  f_2(x_n)=g(x_1,\ldots,x_m)-f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})
  $$
How to continue from this point? Is there another way?  Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that $f$ can be written as $f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})+f_2(x_n)$? To prove the result, all you need is that $f$ and $g$ are maps and $f$ depends on all its variables. "non-constant" and "rational" are unneeded. Even continuity is unnecessary, much less differentiability. "$f$ is dependent on $x_n$" means there exist values of $x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}$ and values $a \ne b$ such that $f(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, a) \ne f(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, b)$. If $m < n$ and $f = g$ as claimed, is that possible?

Comment: Thanks @Paul. I guess thst there is a simple proof.